# tensorflow.while_loop with sample from tensorflow_distribution in condition

Tags: tensorflow, while-loop, tensorflow-probability

I'm struggling to make the following code work. It keeps performing Bernoulli trials until one succeeds.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions

def geometric(p):
    def cond(_):
        return tf.equal(1, tfd.Bernoulli(p).sample())
    def body(t):
        return tf.add(t, 1)
    return tf.while_loop(
        cond, # name is automatically generated
        body,
        [tf.constant(0)]
    )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    acc = sess.run(geometric(0.001))
    print(acc)
```

The above code prints out values from `0` to `3`, which does not makes sense. I'm expecting it to print something in the hundreds. Furthermore, when I change the `geometric` call to `geometric(0.000001)`, I still get the same result.

Can anyone please point out what is wrong with my code above?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the while condition reversed? I think you want while *not* 1 (while 0)

Comment: I managed to fixed the code. That's one of the problems. The other is that the call should be `tfd.Bernoulli(probs=p)`.

Comment: Ah yes. It uses logits by default, the thinking being that most users will typically be doing something like GLM or some neural network parameterization of a classifier. I think there was discussion on the team about making it an error not to use the keyword args, to avoid this very issue.